# Prove the following set is a manifold

Tags: calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

> Let $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ 1 dimensional manifold and $M\subseteq \mathbb{S}^2$ and define
> $N=\{\lambda x:x\in M,\lambda\in(1,2)\}$
> Prove that $N$ is two dimensional manifold

My attempt is because $M$ is one dimensional manifold we can define $f(t)=(g(t),h(t))$ and maybe define another function which will be depend on $t,\lambda$ and get that the new function is two dimensional

Comment: It is not very clear. $M \subset \mathbb R^3$ and $M \subset S^2 $?

Comment: $S^2$ is the unit sphere over $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Perhaps you should use \mathbb{S}^2 : $\mathbb{S}^2$

Comment: any help from you guys?